# Why am I able to manipulate UI elements from a background thread?

Tags: android

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTextView.setText("Hello");
        }
    }).start();
```

But if I add delay for the thread, it doesn't work. So I can manipulate UI elements from a non-UI thread. Can anybody clarify this situation for me?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: He wants to know why he doesn't crash out when setting the TextViews text in a [non main] thread.

Comment: You are right. Why does code above work where I set text of TextView not from UI thread?

Comment: Does the text in the textview change when you run this code as is?

Comment: Yes.!?

but
     Thread.sleep(1*1000);
     mTextView.setText("as");
    
Now it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android doesn't actually stop you from updating the UI from outside the main thread.  It's just more of a ticking time bomb.  If the main UI thread isn't updating the UI at the time, then your thread can do it.  There's just no way of controlling when it's going to happen outside of a `SurfaceView`.

At least that was my understanding.  I don't 100% know for sure, but I've been able to (accidentally) update the UI from outside the main UI thread before.  Sometimes it would work and sometimes it wouldn't, so I assume it was a ConcurrentModificationException of some form.

Comment: I was unaware this would ever work. It was my understanding that this was a hard and fast (enforced) rule. Thanks for the info. Although I would still strongly suggest to the OP that you do not choose to make changes to the UI from different threads, even if it works for you during testing. It may fail on different devices, or under different circumstances.

Comment: It may be a fast-fail in later OS versions, but I do know I've done it before and it was an insanely hard bug to catch cause like I said, it would only sometimes crash.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the one with the sleep with a loop until it finds the opportunity of updating the UI (this would prove it) ?

Comment: I suppose that would work.  Although, I have no idea why a sleep would make any difference.  It seems like it would only crash sometimes as well.  Unless it was a race condition and the sleep allowed Android to swap to the main UI thread before it went back to the new thread.  @Tim: Try and replace the sleep with a permanent loop and send a counter to Logcat to see how many times you update the UI before it crashes.